# Use string instead of "echo"?

Tags: php, string, variables, echo, anonymous-function

Is there any way at all to make a variable work like echo, as such:

```
$x = "echo";
$x "Hi there!";
```

If you understand what I mean? I've seen it done before only the variable was "system" and the code was

```
//taking $x = "system"
$x(blablabla);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why create the extra overhead? Perhaps some context to the problem may be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the notes on `echo`'s manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-notes):

> **Note:** Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions.

If you insist, you could say like `eval "$x \"stuff\";";`, but other than that or creating a function and using it instead, you're kinda out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this:

```
$x = 'printf';
$x('Hi there');
```

?

`echo` is a language construct, not a function, so it won't work